# Make only one button active at a time

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating x number of buttons dynamically based on x number of fetched data.

And I want to make only one button active at a time.
Let's say there are 3 buttons named **A**,**B**,**C**.
When user taps on **B** while **A** is active, I want to deactivate **A** and make **B** active.

It's easily achievable in jQuery like this

`$(this).toggleClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');`

How can I do this in Swift?

I'm creating buttons with the following:

```
let frame1 = CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: 50, height: 30 )
let button1 = UIButton(frame: frame1)
let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "\(distinctCategories[i])".uppercaseString, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: 1.0, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()])
button1.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, forState: .Normal)
button1.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13.0)
button1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
button1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
button1.addTarget(self, action: "filterByCategory:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.categoryScrollView.addSubview(button1)
```

And in the target action I have:

```
func filterByCategory(sender:UIButton) {

    if sender.backgroundColor != UIColor.blackColor() {

        let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "\((sender.titleLabel?.text)!)".uppercaseString, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: 1.0, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
        sender.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, forState: .Selected)
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    } else {

        let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "\((sender.titleLabel?.text)!)".uppercaseString, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: 1.0, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()])
        sender.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, forState: .Normal)
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

I'm only showing the style changes for brevity here.
Currently what I have only handles toggling of sender button style, not the toggling of sibling buttons.

To reverse the style of the sibling buttons, I've tried adding this inside the `if` of the above.

```
for button in categoryScrollView.subviews {
    if let button = button as? UIButton {
        let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: 1.0, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()])      
        button.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, forState: .Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
     }
 }
```

But I'm not sure if I'm doing this right as I need to add all button titles again in this target function for `setAttributedTitle()`

How do other people do this button toggle effect in Swift?

Comment: First: store an array of the created buttons. Then: inside the `filterByCategory` iterate over that array "deactivate" every button that is not the `sender` and "activate" the `sender`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you need is implementation of radio button in iOS.

This can be done using UITableView easily. If your requirement is to use UIButtons in a UIScrollView, then you can store these UIButton Objects in an Array and access them to achieve the effect.

Let's say you have three UIButtons A, B, C. Set their properties for .Selected and .Normal states before adding them in the array. You can set one of them Active as initial state. Also, set unique tags for them for reference

While creating these buttons, add them in an Array (let's say buttons array). Then in the func filterByCategory(sender:UIButton), do the following

```
func filterByCategory(sender:UIButton) {

    sender.selected = true
    for item in array {
        if item.tag != sender.tag {
           item.selected = false
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: You can ping me in the comment if you want to know the method for doing this using UITableView

Comment: You can also use it without tags by moving the first line after the iteration: `arrayOfButtons.forEach { $0.selected = false }; sender.selected = true`.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if setting .Selected and .Normal state will automatically  apply the appropriate style.

Comment: If you set attributes that you want for .Selected and .Normal states properly, then it will be applied automatically. You can change background color also by setting item.backgroundcolor in the loop

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion using a variable to hold the reference to the current button.

The benefit is: No button array and no repeat loop.

- Create an `UIButton` variable `currentButton`.

  ```
  var currentButton : UIButton!
  ```
- Write a method to reset the attributes of the current and set the attributes of the selected button.

  ```
  func selectButton(button: UIButton) {
      if button === currentButton { return }           

      // add the code to reset the attributes of 'currentButton'

      // add the code to set the attributes of 'button'

      currentButton = button
  }
  ```
- After creating the buttons add the *selected* attributes to one of them and set `currentButton` accordingly.
- When a button is tapped call the method

  ```
  func filterByCategory(sender:UIButton) {
     selectButton(sender)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like another solid approach. Does UIButton automatically apply different style if state (.Normal and .Selected) is set? If it requires extra work to define .Normal and .Selected style, what is the process involved?

Comment: Try it out. In the function the two comment lines are placeholders to apply the "unselected" attributes to the current button and the "selected" attributes to the just tapped button like the `if` - `else` clauses in your question.